# Retrofit: is it possible to pass a bean and get a form-encoding?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I'd like to send a `POST` request with a content like the following:

```
api=1&os=android&appVersion=12345
```

Is it possible to have a POJO with just that variables and pass that to

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/sendData")
void sendData(@FieldMap MyPojo myPojo, Callback<MyResponse> callback);
```

With `FieldMap` it doesn't work, is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this won't work out of the box. You have two options:

- If you only have a handful of Pojos, you can define a `MyPojo.toFieldMap()` method to build a field map of form values and pass it to your `sendData()` method.
- If you have a large number of Pojos, you can write a custom `FormEncodedConverter` by implementing the [Converter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/converter/Converter.java) interface in your project. I reckon this will need a combination of annotations and reflection to discover the public members of your `MyPojo` class. Examples of custom converters are available [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters).